# Can i upload and save an image file in file system ,and retrieve it back with javascript or HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, filesystems

I am creating a webpage, which will  be running locally.It will upload a file from local file system and save it in a specific location in that file system.But  I do not want to use any language which require any other installation such as DBMS or web host e.g. JavaScript or Ajax which do not require any installation and can be processed by the browser only.

Comment: You will need a `server side language` to upload the image. `HTML` is just a `markup` language, and `Javascript` in `client` side, ie can't interact with the file system.

Comment: yes it is but i want to know how to work with file system in Javascript and ajax to save file.

Comment: You can't. They are `client side`

Comment: so you mean there must be a server side language to process  the request for saving  the file in a standalone machine?

Comment: Yes, if you want to interact/upload/move files, you would need a web server, if you're running this locally, you can download WAMP/MAMP/LAMP stack (Win/Mac/Linux), and code away :)

Comment: ok i got you thanks!!!.But i was wondering if there's a way to process these things without using php or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**  You cannot normally access to filesystem with client-side Javascript.

**But! ..**

**.. you can with Javascript on server**
(NodeJs with FS API http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

**.. and you can, but only in Chrome** and only with `chrome.fileSystem` api.
http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html

Manual on HTML5rocks - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/